SwiftUI ARView unable to adjust size and alignment
I want to have an ARView but only partial display at the middle of iPhone, so I created some code below
this is the container of ARView
struct ARViewContainer : UIViewRepresentable {
    var arViewModel: ARViewModel
    
    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> MyARView {
        arViewModel.startSessionDelegate()
        return arViewModel.arView
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: MyARView, context: Context) {}
}

this is the ARViewModel
struct ARModel {
    private(set) var arView : ARView
    
    init() {
        let rect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let frameRect = CGRect(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY, width: rect.width, height: rect.height/4)
        print(frameRect)

        arView = ARView(frame: frameRect)

        let config = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
        config.planeDetection = [.horizontal]
        arView.session.run(config)
    }
}

class ARViewModel: UIViewController, ObservableObject, ARSessionDelegate {
    @Published private var model : ARModel = ARModel()
    @Published var mapImage: UIImage?
    
    var arView : MyARView {
        model.arView
    }

    func startSessionDelegate() {
        model.arView.session.delegate = self
    }
  
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {}

    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        if let image = UIImage(pixelBuffer: frame.capturedImage) {
            mapImage = LocSystem.rotateImage(image)
        }    
    }  
}

this is the ContentView
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var arViewModel : ARViewModel = ARViewModel()

    @State var mapImage: UIImage?

    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack {
            if let image = arViewModel.mapImage {
                Image(uiImage: image)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .border(Color.red)
                    .background(Color.cyan)
            } else {
                Color.gray
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                ProgressView()
            }

            ARViewContainer(arViewModel: arViewModel)
                .scaledToFill()
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .frame(height: UIScreen.main.bounds.height / 4, alignment: .top)
                .border(Color.blue)
                .cornerRadius(15)
                .padding(25)
       
                Spacer()
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}

At last, the result turns out like this

The background is the ARView captured image, The middle frame(ARView) is small but the picture is aligned center. I want to align it .top. I can't change its crop size, alignment and so. Seems like ARView is so stubborn. Why? Please help
